# A generic error occured in GDI+ in winform

Tags: vb.net

I'm facing a problem in windows application. I want to update a picture but it generates exception:
"*A generic error occured in GDI+*"

Here is my code:

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream
PicMeter.Image.Save(ms, PicMeter.Image.RawFormat) 'here exception occurs
Dim arr As Byte() = ms.GetBuffer()
ms.Close()
```

Comment: PicMeter is PictureBox Name

Comment: @the_lotus he's doing this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx
Trying to save an image TO a stream

Comment: has my answer has helped?

Comment: thanks to you.it generates execption when image formate is jpeg,bmp.but it works fine on png format picture.so i enforece filter on open dialogue box.

Comment: that'll be because png is a raw format where as jpeg and bmps are not. You'll need to set the imageformat dynamically based on a users selection if you want to handle different types. For example ImageFormat.Gif will handle gifs.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
PicMeter.Image.Save(ms, PicMeter.Image.RawFormat)
```

to

```
PicMeter.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.RawFormat)
```

If that doesn't help, does it help to create a new image and save it from there? As suggested here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/49392-pictureboximage-save-error/

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream
Dim bitmp As New Bitmap(PicMeter.Image)
bitmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.RawFormat)
Dim arr As Byte() = ms.GetBuffer()
ms.Close()
```